# Invoice is not printing at right side

Tags: javascript, html

I am using following code to print my html content.
My code is below

Code is ok I am facing problem that

```js
function printDiv(divId) {
      window.frames["print_frame"].document.body.innerHTML = document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML;
      window.frames["print_frame"].window.focus();
      window.frames["print_frame"].window.print();
  };
```

```html
<span class="print">
<a href="javascript:printDiv('invoice')">print</a>
 <iframe name="print_frame" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" src="about:blank"></iframe>
 </span>

 <div id="invoice" style="margin: 10px 20px;margin-bottom: 35px;-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px #ccc;box-shadow: 0 0 6px #ccc;">
               
<div style="float:right;width:35%;text-align:right;">
    <span style="font-size: 24pt;right: 0 ">INVOICE</span>
 <br> <span style="font-size: 10pt;right: 0"><b># 345</b></span>
</div>
   ....
   </div
```

My problem is INVOICE is not showing at fully right side.
HOw to resolve this

Comment: What is the error you are getting? what is `divId` in the function.

Comment: But it is a variable, where it is defined and initialized/

Comment: Please see code I have edited it

Answer (score 0):

The body adds 8px margin. Could this be the issue? You could resolve it by adding the following CSS:

```
body {
   margin: 0;
}
```

Or if you can't do this just push the invoice text further to the right:

```
<span style="font-size: 24pt;right: -8px ">INVOICE</span>
<br> <span style="font-size: 10pt;right: -8px;"><b># 345</b></span>
```